# Pandas I want to drop rows with NaT based on another column's value

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a df that looks like:

```
id  | Type | Start                  | End
1    1       0 days 00:00:52.132432  0 days 00:01:34.123875
2    1       0 days 00:00:52.543265  NaT
3    2       0 days 00:00:52.765434  1 days 00:00:23.123763
```

I only want where the Type equals 1 and where the end time isn't NaT, so all that should be returned is:

```
id  | Type | Start                  | End
1    1       0 days 00:00:52.132432  0 days 00:01:34.123875
```

What is the best way to go around this? The final step that I want to implement is that the rows that fit this criteria will have their start time amended. Eg this row above will then be transformed to:

```
id  | Type | Start                  | End
1    1       0 days 00:00:33.987658  0 days 00:01:34.123875
```

Comment: What does mean `have their start time amended` ? Can you add sample?

Comment: Amended. I was thinking that would probably be within a if statement to for loop but I know with pandas that there are easier ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df.loc[((df.Type == 1) & (df.End.notnull())), :]

   id  Type                   Start                     End
0   1     1  0 days 00:00:52.132432  0 days 00:01:34.123875
```